# How to make easy transfer data from wpf to Unity? (Make level creation automatic)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, automation

I'm developing a rhythm game, and for it I created simple WPF program for automatize level creation.

After clicking the <kbd>Beat</kbd> button, time of the click is stored in Table.

All I need to do, is take `TIME` from this wpf program and assign the value to a `Projectile.y` value.

The problem is, I have 600 of "beats" and if I assign `y` to all of them manually, it is a lot of overkill for me. So how can I solve this problem and get the values assigned automatically?

[image]

Comment: Write your timings to a text file in your WPF application, put it in the assets folder, and load it into Unity using the TextAsset class.

Comment: Could you give us a few more details? Can you store the  WPF times in a text file? What is  `Projectile.y`? Do you mean the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution was easy - I just write text file with all time elemets, and then Parsed it to float in Unity.